# If the memory allocated be freed after constructor throw exception

Tags: c++

I know `Object *pObject=new Object` contain two steps:

1. operator new to allocate memory
2. call object's constructor.

and call `delete pObject`:

1. call object's destruct;
2. operator delete to free memory.

But when new Object process, if the step 2 throw exception, if the operator delete be called to free memory by system?

Comment: Do not throw exceptions in the constructor.

Comment: @EdHeal, Why not? It seems one of the common ways to deal with errors while constructing an object, and given it being written correctly, should not leak or anything.

Comment: yes, the `operator delete` at the same format with the `operator new` called will be called.

Comment: @jiafu, Yes, assuming an appropriate `delete` available (which might not be there if it's an overloaded `new`), it will be called.

Comment: A technicality, the operator `new` doesn't call itself, rather it allocates the space (similar to `malloc`) and then calls the constructor. Similar with `delete`. Although there are other subtleties.

Comment: @chris, are you sure of your answer, any official article can be refered?

Comment: @chris - Consider that the constructor gets half way through and make network connections etc. Throws a wobbly. Does the person calling the constructor know how far it is got and when to release?

Comment: @EdHeal, the constructor should clean up before throwing the exception. Read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors-can-throw.html. Using RAII throwing in constructors is perfectly safe and preferable, how would you handle such a situation?

Comment: @EdHeal, That would classify as an incorrectly written constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, the destructor is not called. As the object isn't constructed properly it would be unsafe to call the destructor. However if any member objects have been constructed fully then they are destructed (as the object is complete).

Some people recommend against throwing in constructors, I believe it is better than zombie states which is akin to error codes and makes verbose code. So long as you follow RAII you should be fine (each resource is managed by it's own object). Before you throw in the constructor make sure that you clean up anything you've half done, but again, if you're using RAII that should be nothing.

The following outputs "B":

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
  ~B() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

struct A {
  A() : b() { throw(1); }
  ~A() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
  B b;
};

int main() {
  try {
    A *a = new A;
    delete a;
  } catch(int a) {}
}
```

**Edit:**
The above isn't what you asked, yes the delete operator is called, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[] says:

"These deallocation functions are called by delete-expressions and by new-expressions to deallocate memory after destructing (or failing to construct) objects with dynamic storage duration."

This could be tested by overriding the operator `delete`.

Comment: I know the destruct won't be called, but I am't now sure if the operator delete if be called.

Comment: No `delete` will not be called because `delete` calls the destructor. You are confusing `malloc`/`free` and `new`/`delete`.

Comment: No, the operator `delete` will always call the destructor. I think what you're trying to ask is if the memory is left allocated (a leak) then no, the memory is unallocated (similar to a `free` being called).

Comment: The memory location is lost once you hit the exception handler so there would be no point in leaving it allocated.

Comment: http://ideone.com/QZF0XP  Which shows that the pointer is null and not assigned a location. Thus no leaks occured.. Assuming that the class threw before it allocated anything.. Construction did take place but it wasn't complete..

Comment: @jaifu I was wrong, the operator `delete` does not call the destructor. See the link in my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the operator delete will be called to release the memory allocated.

The program below can prove that:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A { 
public:
    A() { cout << "A() at " << this << endl; throw 1; }
    ~A() { cout << "~A() at " << this << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        try {
            new A;
        } catch (int a) {
            // pass
        }   
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program on my system, I find that the result printed out are like this:

```
A() at 0x2170010
A() at 0x2170010
A() at 0x2170010
```

Obviously, the destructors are NOT call because NO

```
~A() at 0x2170010
```

lines are printed out.

And the operator delete are surely called because the addresses of the three objects are exactly the same.